# Shouldn't this be the standard way to prove that if $p>1$ then $p^n \to +\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

**Proposition:**
*Let* $p>1$. *We have* $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} p^n = +\infty.$$

My professor proved this setting $p=1+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ and then using Bernoulli's inequality and the comparison theorem.
Apart from using the definition of divergence, is this the standard way?
I guess my question sort of regards didactics. I'm asking because I feel like the following is more elementary:

$\{p^n\}$ is strictly increasing: $$p^{n+1}>p^n \iff \frac{p^{n+1}}{p^n} =p>1 $$ therefore if it doesn't diverge, it must approach $\alpha\in (1,+\infty)$. But then so does $\{p^{n+1}\}$, which implies $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p^{n+1}}{p^n}=p=\frac\alpha\alpha=1,$$ contradicting the assumption $p>1$.

I avoided using directly the ratio test as it seems to be more advanced, at least according to my book.

Comment: It's a fine proof, but classes often use proofs that try to make other ideas comfortable. Also, Bernoulli is easily proven, why proving that if $a_n,b_n$ converge to the same non-zero value that $a_n/b_n$ requires a fair amount of effort. It also assumes the least upper bound property, but the above proof works where the LUB does not, say, in the rationals.

Comment: Your proof is essentially assuming that $p^n$ is convergent then arrive a contradiction. Yes I think your prove can in a sense be easier. However prove by contradiction of this type doesn't provide as much intuition about  why it diverges as to the prove that your professor mentioned about

Comment: My first instinct would be the same as your professor's -- except I wouldn't mention Bernoulli (only learned what "Bernoulli's inequality" was when I googled after writing most of an answer), but just motivate it as an obvious consequence of the binomial theorem ...

Comment: In your proof you shouldn't just say $\frac{p^{n+1}}{p^n}$ you should involve the limit.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Yes, thanks, I corrected the typo.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I see, thank you.

Comment: The reason why I think the proof using Bernoulli would be prefered is that your other proof requires monotone convergence theorem, which might be proven later, while this limit can appear right after defining notion of convergence.

Comment: @Wojowu: Makes sense, thank you.